# axis ticks labels are unreadable too close

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have been working on a special drawing for a considerable amount of time - fortunately, it's almost done. The whole thing is based on plotting magnitude of a complex function over the complex plane. I would like to avoid using an external dat file.

Since the function has not its poles in infinity, I had to set high `samples` to plot steep poles correctly in details.

Now, this higher `samples` numbers often led to an TeX capacity error and manual increasing (for MiKTeX) was not very effective.

For that reason, I divided area: samplings around the poles are finer and for the rest of the plot, which is not so interesting and basically smooth, coarser number of samples is used. Only then compilation has been successful.

When `view={50}{45}` is used in `axis` environment (which fits original purposes of drawing perfectly), ugly discontinuities are hidden! So this similar `view` setup is preferred.

I have already solved out some issues that have arisen, but one more problem remains.

I would like to have `ticks labels` on `x axis`, but you you can the result I got:
[image]

`x ticks labels` are too close so they overlap each other.

When default `view` is used, x ticks labels are ok, BUT:

**a)** view is not good for *didactic* purposes, because the thick red line is deformed too much and is not acceptable
**b)** diffeerent sampled areas and their boundaries are clearly visible

From this point, I tried `extra ticks` in this manner [how to move extra x tick label vertically down](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330757/pgfplots-how-to-move-extra-x-tick-label-vertically-down) to take away `tick labels` from the `x axis`, but it only gave weird "crosses" on x axis. But this is the way I suggest - make these `\Re` `x ticks` further away from the axis, which is still nice looking solution.

Then, I was labouring with [Adjusting the distance between label and axis in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119411/adjusting-the-distance-between-label-and-axis-in-pgfplots), but I simply don't understand it properly and I wasn't able to make it work for me.

Finally, I also tried make some sort of "quasi-extra ticks" manually using `draw` command, but it turned out the worst of all because these quasi-ticks disappeared... what a shame :)

So, what I would like to get is `x ticks labels` which are not overlaping each other and similar position of graph. Of course, I can discuss the `view` option if it would lead to a good result.

Good result means: no **visible** sampling discontinuities, thick red line should be (just a bit) recognisible **recognizable** as function from my elder, previous post [Piecewise-defined function badly colored](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380426/piecewise-defined-function-badly-colored) and clear axis tick labels.

Any help is welcome :)

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}%set a compat!!
%%%%%%% 
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={argsinh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(\x^2+1));}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={argcosh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(-1 + \x)*sqrt(1 + \x));}}
%%4th order normed low pass, Chebyshev
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={H(\x,\y) = .125297/(sqrt((\x^4-6*\x^2*\y^2+\y^4+.581580*\x^3-1.744740*\x*\y^2+1.169118*\x^2-1.169118*\y^2+.404768*\x+.176987)^2+(4*\x^3*\y-4*\x*\y^3+1.744740*\x^2*\y-.581580*\y^3+2.338236*\x*\y+.404768*\y)^2));}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle, axis on top,
    axis equal image,
    width=40cm, %%ridi velikost grafu! 
    view={50}{45},      
    xmin=-0.5,
    xmax=0.5,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2,
    zmin=0,
    zmax=2,
    miter limit=1,    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    xlabel=$\Sigma$,
    xlabel style={anchor=east,xshift=-5pt,at={(xticklabel* cs:.95)}},% <- position the x label
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    ylabel=$j\Omega$,
    zlabel=$\mathopen| H(j\Omega)\mathclose|$,
    zlabel style={anchor=north east},% <- position the z label
    xtick = {0,-.205619531335967,-.851703985681571e-1},
    hide obscured x ticks=false,% <- added    
    xticklabels = {0,$\Re(s_4)$,$\Re(s_3)$},
    hide obscured y ticks=false,% <- added    
    ytick = {.392046688799926,.946484433184241},
    yticklabels = {$\Im(s_4)$,$\Im(s_3)$},
    ztick = \empty,          
    ]

    %%pole position as projection
    \addplot3[dotted,black] coordinates {
        (0,.946484433184241,0)
        (-.851703985681571e-1,.946484433184241,0)
        (-.851703985681571e-1,0,0)
    };
    %%standard circle symbol for pole
    \draw[black, thin] (-.851703985681571e-1,.946484433184241,0) circle [radius=0.03];

    %%pole position as projection
    \addplot3[dotted,black] coordinates {
        (0,.392046688799926,0)
        (-.205619531335967,.392046688799926,0)
        (-.205619531335967,0,0)
    };  
    %%standard circle symbol for pole
    \draw[black, thin] (-.205619531335967,.392046688799926,0) circle [radius=0.03];

    %%pole position as projection / vertical lines
    \addplot3[dotted,black] coordinates {        
        (-.205619531335967,.392046688799926,0)
        (-.205619531335967,.392046688799926,1.5)
    };

    \addplot3[
        smooth,     
        surf,
        faceted color=black,
        line width=0.01pt,      
        fill=white,                             
        domain=-0.75:0,
        y domain = 0:1.5,
        samples = 50,
        samples y = 50,
        restrict z to domain*=0:1.5]        
        {H(\x,\y)};

    \addplot3[
        smooth,
        surf,
        faceted color=black,
        line width=0.01pt,      
        fill=white,                             
        domain=-0.4:0,
        y domain = 0:1.2,
        samples = 40,
        samples y = 60,             
        restrict z to domain*=0:1.5]        
        {H(\x,\y)};

    %%pole position as projection / vertical lines
    \addplot3[dotted,black] coordinates {        
        (-.851703985681571e-1,.946484433184241,0)
        (-.851703985681571e-1,.946484433184241,0.85)         
    };  

    %%red characteristics
    \addplot3[domain=0:1.5,samples=70, samples y = 0, red, thick] ({0},{x},{H(0,x)});

    %%ellipse for poles: order 4, eps=1 (3dB]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\elipseA}{sinh((1/4)*argsinh(1/1))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\elipseB}{cosh((1/4)*argsinh(1/1))}
    \draw[thin,dashed,blue] (0,\elipseB,0) arc (90:270:{\elipseA} and {\elipseB});
    \end{axis}

    %%manually added extra-like x ticks (in case of different view)


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nitpick: I would start by stopping using those symbols for Re and Im  for didactic purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reorder the `xtick` and the `xticklabels` and shift the `xticklabels` manuelly depending on the `\ticknum`:

```
xtick = {0,-.851703985681571e-1,-.205619531335967},
xticklabels = {0,$\Re(s_3)$,$\Re(s_4)$},
xticklabel style={
  yshift=6pt*(\ticknum>0?1:0)+3pt*(\ticknum>1?1:0),
  xshift=-4pt*(\ticknum>0?1:0)-2pt*(\ticknum>1?1:0)
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}%set a compat!!
%%%%%%% 
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={argsinh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(\x^2+1));}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={argcosh(\x) = ln(\x + sqrt(-1 + \x)*sqrt(1 + \x));}}
%%4th order normed low pass, Chebyshev
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={H(\x,\y) = .125297/(sqrt((\x^4-6*\x^2*\y^2+\y^4+.581580*\x^3-1.744740*\x*\y^2+1.169118*\x^2-1.169118*\y^2+.404768*\x+.176987)^2+(4*\x^3*\y-4*\x*\y^3+1.744740*\x^2*\y-.581580*\y^3+2.338236*\x*\y+.404768*\y)^2));}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle, axis on top,
    axis equal image,
    width=40cm, %%ridi velikost grafu! 
    view={50}{45},      
    xmin=-0.5,
    xmax=0.5,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2,
    zmin=0,
    zmax=2,
    miter limit=1,    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    xlabel=$\Sigma$,
    xlabel style={anchor=east,xshift=-5pt,at={(xticklabel* cs:.95)}},% <- position the x label
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    ylabel=$j\Omega$,
    zlabel=$\mathopen| H(j\Omega)\mathclose|$,
    zlabel style={anchor=north east},% <- position the z label
    xtick = {0,-.851703985681571e-1,-.205619531335967},
    xticklabels = {0,$\Re(s_3)$,$\Re(s_4)$},
    xticklabel style={
      yshift=6pt*(\ticknum>0?1:0)+3pt*(\ticknum>1?1:0),
      xshift=-4pt*(\ticknum>0?1:0)-2pt*(\ticknum>1?1:0)
    },
    hide obscured x ticks=false,% <- added
    %hide obscured y ticks=false,% <- added
    ytick = {.392046688799926,.946484433184241},
    yticklabels = {$\Im(s_4)$,$\Im(s_3)$},
    ztick = \empty,
    ]

    %%pole position as projection
    \addplot3[dotted,black] coordinates {
        (0,.946484433184241,0)
        (-.851703985681571e-1,.946484433184241,0)
        (-.851703985681571e-1,0,0)
    };
    %%standard circle symbol for pole
    \draw[black, thin] (-.851703985681571e-1,.946484433184241,0) circle [radius=0.03];

    %%pole position as projection
    \addplot3[dotted,black] coordinates {
        (0,.392046688799926,0)
        (-.205619531335967,.392046688799926,0)
        (-.205619531335967,0,0)
    };  
    %%standard circle symbol for pole
    \draw[black, thin] (-.205619531335967,.392046688799926,0) circle [radius=0.03];

    %%pole position as projection / vertical lines
    \addplot3[dotted,black] coordinates {        
        (-.205619531335967,.392046688799926,0)
        (-.205619531335967,.392046688799926,1.5)
    };

    \addplot3[
        smooth,
        surf,
        faceted color=black,
        line width=0.01pt, 
        fill=white,
        domain=-0.75:0,
        y domain = 0:1.5,
        samples = 50,
        samples y = 50,
        restrict z to domain*=0:1.5]
        {H(\x,\y)};

    \addplot3[
        smooth,
        surf,
        faceted color=black,
        line width=0.01pt,
        fill=white,
        domain=-0.4:0,
        y domain = 0:1.2,
        samples = 40,
        samples y = 60,
        restrict z to domain*=0:1.5]
        {H(\x,\y)};

    %%pole position as projection / vertical lines
    \addplot3[dotted,black] coordinates {
        (-.851703985681571e-1,.946484433184241,0)
        (-.851703985681571e-1,.946484433184241,0.85)
    };  

    %%red characteristics
    \addplot3[domain=0:1.5,samples=70, samples y = 0, red, thick] ({0},{x},{H(0,x)});

    %%ellipse for poles: order 4, eps=1 (3dB]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\elipseA}{sinh((1/4)*argsinh(1/1))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\elipseB}{cosh((1/4)*argsinh(1/1))}
    \draw[thin,dashed,blue] (0,\elipseB,0) arc (90:270:{\elipseA} and {\elipseB});
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know these shifts and its acceptable.Anyway, do you know how to make extra ticks in 3d case?

Comment: Ok, I marked it as solved. I really like your solution, this is the first time I saw such usage :) Nice